# Import data of specific columns using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<h3 id="LABandServerNamingConvention-:"><a href="/display/ES/Lab+Org+Code+Summary+Listing">Lab Org Code Summary Listing</a>:</h3>
<div class="sectionColumnWrapper">
  <div class="sectionMacro">
    <div class="sectionMacroRow">
      <div class="columnMacro">
        <div class="table-wrap">
          <table class="confluenceTable">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th class="confluenceTh">
                  <p>Prefix</p>
                </th>
                <th class="confluenceTh">
                  <p>Group</p>
                </th>
                <th class="confluenceTh">
                  <p>Contact</p>
                </th>
                <th class="confluenceTh">
                  <p>Dev/Test Lab</p>
                </th>
                <th class="confluenceTh">
                  <p>Performance</p>
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                  <p>SEE00</p>
                </td>
                <td class="confluenceTd">
                  <p>Entertainment</p>
                </td>
<tr><td class="confluenceTd"><p>SEF00</p></td><td class="confluenceTd"><p>APTRA Vision</p></td><td class="confluenceTd"><p> </p></td><td class="confluenceTd"><p><a href="/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=83909590">VCD Lab</a> , <a href="/display/ES/SEF00+%28+Aptra+Vision%29+-+Virtual+Lab+Details">Test Lab</a></p></td>
```

I have a table with 5 columns out of which 2 are filled for this specific entry. 
How do I get the row data from the table into my python code from this HTML snippet. I am using BeautifulSoup. This is what I have tried so far:

```
data           = requests.get(url,auth=(username,password))
sample         = data.content
soup           = BeautifulSoup(sample,'html.parser')
article_text   = ' '
article        = soup.findAll('td', {'class' : "confluenceTd" })    
for element in article:
article_text += '\n' + ''.join(element.findAll(text = True))
```

I want to somehow get 'SEE00' and 'Entertainment'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = '''<h3 id="LABandServerNamingConvention-:"><a href="/display/ES/Lab+Org+Code+Summary+Listing">Lab Org Code Summary Listing</a>:</h3>
<div class="sectionColumnWrapper"><div class="sectionMacro"><div class="sectionMacroRow"><div class="columnMacro"><div class="table-wrap"><table class="confluenceTable"><tbody><tr><th class="confluenceTh"><p>Prefix</p></th><th class="confluenceTh"><p>Group</p></th><th class="confluenceTh"><p>Contact</p></th><th class="confluenceTh"><p>Dev/Test Lab</p></th><th class="confluenceTh"><p>Performance</p></th></tr><tr><td class="confluenceTd"><p>SEE00</p></td><td class="confluenceTd"><p>Entertainment</p></td>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'lxml')

for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    print(row.get_text(separator='\t')) # this separator is only for format, you can use whatever you want
```

out:

```
Prefix  Group   Contact Dev/Test Lab    Performance
SEE00   Entertainment
```

you can control the for loop with slice:

```
for row in soup.find_all('tr')[1:]:
```

this will only print

```
SEE00   Entertainment
```

update:

in:

```
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    row_data = row.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')[:2]
    print(row_data)
```

out:

```
['Prefix', 'Group']
['SEE00', 'Entertainment']
['SEF00', 'APTRA Vision']
```

Comment: Ok but would this work if my webpage is dynamically changing?

Comment: beautifulsoup + requests cannot handle javascript

Comment: Also one question, suppose my table had more data, say something like SEE00  Entertainment  +1933993  Dev Lab   98%                                                  then is there a way I can just get SEE00 and Entertainment?

Comment: update you html code, and i will give you a solution.

Comment: Hi. I have updated HTML code. Now I just wanted to get SEF00 and APTRA Vision. I dont want "VCD Lab" and "Dev Lab".